# Google Play Achievement description text length

Tags: android, formatting, google-play, google-play-services, achievements

Is there a way to alter the display of the google play achievement view, where you see the achievements and there descriptions. Each achievement has space for up to 500 characters on Google play and yet, only roughly ~50 characters can be displayed on the achievements screen (depending on the device we run the game on).

Is there a way to have more text appear on the achievement screen, either by scrolling the hidden text or enlarging the boxes?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to alter the layout, the default views for Google Play Games are very fixed.

If you have long descriptions and the default layout isn't working for you, you'll have to implement your own achievements view and use Games.Achievements.load() to get the data.

Comment: Why does google play allow 500 characters then if there's no way of altering the layout? this seems like an oversight, no?

Comment: Well like I said, if you implement your own Achievements UI you can display descriptions up to that 500 characters. It wouldn't make sense if you **had** to use the default UI, but you're not limited to just that layout.